# How do I solve this regex match/replace in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, gruntjs

I have the following input:

```
<script src="common/scripts/vendor.0.js"></script>
<script src="common/scripts/all.0.js"></script>
<script src="common/scripts/config.js"></script>
```

I'm trying to write a Grunt task to do a match/replace with JavaScript regex to something like this:

```
{
    match: /<(script.*?src=)"(.*?)"(.*?)>/g,
    replacement: '<$1"//<%= config.cdn.preview[0] %>/$2"$3>'
}
```

And I get this output:

```
<script src="//cdn.domain.com/common/scripts/vendor.0.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.domain.com/common/scripts/all.0.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.domain.com/common/scripts/config.js"></script>
```

So far so good... The only thing is... I don't want to do the match/replace the line with the `config.js` file, only the other two. I want the output to be this:

```
<script src="//cdn.domain.com/common/scripts/vendor.0.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.domain.com/common/scripts/all.0.js"></script>
<script src="common/scripts/config.js"></script>
```

I've tried countless things I found here on SO and Google but can't seem to find a solution for this.

Comment: It may be easiest to use [`grunt-regex-replace`](https://github.com/bomsy/grunt-regex-replace) to specify the directory (minus `config.js`) that you want to do the match/replace on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 \*ducks\*

Comment: What is the spec for the lines you want to replace? Just NO to config? Or YES to all 0.js?

Comment: @Sam I don't see how that task would help. It seems to do exactly the same as the one I'm using.

Comment: @zx81 NO to config. The number will change with the build number.

Comment: You should be able to set a source like: `src: ['./scripts/**/*.js', '!./scripts/config.js']`

Comment: And config is only specified in environment.js?

Comment: @Sam I'm not sure I understand that. The src attribute is the file(s) to read the contents from and then to the match/replace. I'm processing the index.html file, which contains my input with all those script tags.

Comment: @zx81 I'm sorry, that was a typo, please refresh the question, I just updated it.

Comment: OH! I get your question. Sorry, nevermind me.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral `I just updated it.` And I updated the answer. :)

Comment: FY Added explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to exclude the line with `config.js' This is what you can do:

Search:

```
<script src="common(?![\w/]+config\.js)
```

Replace:

```
<script src="//cdn.domain.common
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/dK0rD1) (look at the substitutions section at the bottom)

Your exact search and replacement criteria may be different, but I'm sure you'll be able to tweak that.

**How does it work?**

1. `<script src="common` looks for scripts starting with common
2. The `(?![\w/]+config\.js)` negative lookahead asserts that what immediately follows is not a number of word characters and slashes followed by `config.js`

Comment: @Sam The `.*?` would be a problem if you have two scripts on the same line, it will eat over the end of the first script. See this [demo](http://regex101.com/r/eB7yU5): the first two no longer match.

Comment: Ugh I'm out of it today, all distracted by the 3D printer I just kickstarted haha..removing my comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral What do you mean? See the substitutions on the demo: the output strings are what you wanted. Why do you want to "catch" something more? (Not understanding your question.)

Comment: I'm not doing that on my original question, but say I also wanted to make sure that that regex would match the final `</script>`? Maybe I shouldn't be doing this, but I was just wondering.

Comment: @RicardoAmaral That's not a problem with an additional lookahead, either just before or just after the negative lookahead. But for your specs, I don't see the need to give the regex engine more work.